# Como parsear correctamente en C#

Tags: c#, parsear

Buscando parseo, encontré lo siguiente:

```
Int32.Parse(string);
Convert.ToInt32(string);
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Cual es la mejor manera de parsear, que sea mas efectiva y el por que. En que caso se ocupa una forma, y en que caso otra

Comment: Respuesta rápida: Hacen lo mismo, diferencias: Arrojan distintas excepciones cuando intentas llamarlas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mencioné en un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62538/como-parsear-correctamente-en-c/62546#comment113390_62538) hace un rato que *"Ambas hacen lo mismo, salvo que arrojan distintas excepciones en base al valor que 'parsean'."*

Dicho esto [(fuente)](https://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32), tienes lo siguiente:

```
string convertToInt = "12";
string nullString = null;
string maxValue = "32222222222222222222222222222222222";
string formatException = "12.32";

int parseResult;

// Convertirá correctamente.
parseResult = int.Parse(convertToInt);

// Arrojará NullException.
parseResult = int.Parse(nullString); 

// Arrojará OverflowException .
parseResult = int.Parse(maxValue);

// Arrojará FormatException.
parseResult = int.Parse(formatException);


// Lo mismo, utilizando Convert.ToInt32

// Funcionará perfecto.
parseResult = Convert.ToInt32(convertToInt);

// Retornará Cero si el string es null.
parseResult = Convert.ToInt32(nullString);

// Arrojará OverflowException
parseResult = Convert.ToInt32(maxValue);

// Arrojará FormatException
parseResult = Convert.ToInt32(formatException);
```

Puedes probar un Fiddle [aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1YT2pV). :)

### EDIT:

[`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) tiene distintas sobrecargas que permiten castear prácticamente cualquier cosa a `int`, sin embargo a [`int.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) sólo puedes pasarle `string`, arrojando las respectivas excepciones mencionadas anteriormente en cadad caso, mencionando que `int.Parse()` posee varias sobrecargas para especificar el formato del número.

## EDIT 2:

Al final, muy muy en el fondo, ambas implementaciones llaman a un método llamado `Number.Parse` que es interno de .NET Framework, vease el código fuente de ambas funciones más abajo<sup>1</sup>:

```
// Int32.Parse(String s) Implementación.
[Pure]
public static int Parse(String s) {
    return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

// Convert.ToInt32(String value) implementación.
public static int ToInt32(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Lo que deja dicho, a nivel de llamadas, sí, puede que `Int32.Parse(string)` sea más rápido, dado que ahorra una llamada interna, no como `Convert.ToInt32(object)`, que primero evalua el objeto a convertir y luego llama al método `Parse()`.

<sup>1</sup>: Código fuente de ambas implementaciones gracias a Reference Source *Vease: [`Convert.ToInt32(string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1112) e [`Int32.Parse(string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,119).*

Comment: Tome su +1 mi buen amigo cloruro :) muy buena respesta.

Comment: < leerse con voz del bananero > el cloruro zappe! </ leerse con voz del bananero >

Comment: Alguna es mas efectiva que la otra? Consulto, por que cuando estaba estudiando, el profe que tenia tenia certificaciones de microsoft y siempre nos decía que había una forma de parsear o castear mas rápida que la otra. En términos de pequeño dato, no era visible, pero si en grandes cantidades

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda Puede ver el edit.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta tan completa :D

Answer (score 0):

Ambas formas son validas, una la diferencia que veo es que el Convert.ToInt32() permite asignar varios tipos de datos como parametro

[Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)

mientras que el Int32.Parse() solo puede pasarle un string

[Int32.Parse (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)

ambas son validas

Si tienes el

[Int32.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

por si quieres validar la converison sin recibir una Exception

Comment: Alguna es mas efectiva que la otra? Consulto, por que cuando estaba estudiando, el profe que tenia tenia certificaciones de microsoft y siempre nos decía que había una forma de parsear o castear mas rápida que la otra. En términos de pequeño dato, no era visible, pero si en grandes cantidades